# What is the C# .NET Silverlight equivalent of componentsSeparatedByString in Objective-C?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, silverlight, windows-phone-7

What is the C# .NET Silverlight equivalent of componentsSeparatedByString in Objective-C?

Here is how the method works in Objective-C:

```
NSString *namesStr =  @"John;Michael;Jason";
NSArray *namesArray = [namesStr componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
```

Is there anything like this with C# .NET for a List?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use [`string.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

```
var names = namesStr.Split(';');
```

Comment: If you wanted `names` to be a `List<string>` just append a `.ToList()`, otherwise this doesn't change anything